# Accessing variable value without declaring it in function prototype

Tags: c, function, pointers

In the function `read`, I need to access the values of integer `a` and integer `b` from the `main` function without declaring them in the prototype of the function `read`, using pointers.
Pointer `x` should point to integer `a`, and pointer `y` should point to integer `b`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void read(int zzz[], int n) {
    int *arr = zzz, *x=a,*y=b;
}
int main() {
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    return 0;
}
```

How this could be implemented?

Comment: Your function doesn't use the `n` argument; variables `a` and `b` are not visible in the function.  You don't call the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways that the `read` function can read the values or addresses of `a` and `b`:

- Pass them as parameters
- Make `a` and `b` global

So if you don't want to make them parameters, you need to move them outside of the `main` function and before the `read` function.

Also, `read` is the name of a system function, so you should name it something else so you don't conflict with it.

Answer (score 0):

---

You have already received the more conventional answer. It is the most logical choice for your given restriction.

---

*However* ... Silly artificial restrictions sometimes deserve a silly contrived solution in kind.

A less conventional way would be to create an understanding with the function that the values will be passed in with the array pointer in some non-standard way.

For example, you can make two extra array members to represent `a` and `b`.

```
int array_for_my_read[array_size + 2];
/* instead of a and b, you use those extra array members */
...
int *x = zzz + n, *y = x + 1;
```

Alternatively, you could create a special structure that holds the array, and the pointers. Then the function recovers the pointer to the structure from the array pointer.

```
struct extra_parameters {
    int *a;
    int *b;
    int zzz[zzz_size];
};
...
struct extra_parameters x;
int a, b;
x.a = &a;
x.b = &b;
read(x.zzz, zzz_size);
...
void *p = (char *)zzz - offsetof(struct extra_parameters, zzz);
struct extra_parameters *xp = p;
int *a = xp->a, *b = xp->b;
```

Comment: we dont know that its a silly restriction, it might be a 'lost in translation' problem. OP may have been asked to pass by refence rather than value (we dont knwo if read intends to modify a and b) but not understood when that was explained to them

Comment: The OP explicitly mentions *without declaring it in the prototype of the function* and *using pointers*. I think lost in translation would just not mention any restrictions at all. (Which is more typical and more irksome, since solutions get rejected because restrictions were not mentioned.)

Comment: well he says, "without declaring it, using pointers" which can be read as "dont use int x, use a pointer". If that comma was 'or' I would agree

Comment: @pm100 If your objection is based on not wanting to lead the OP astray, I can empathize. However, contrived restrictions like this occur in the real world as well. The closest analog would be a callback function that passes the pointer to a data buffer that it populates. If you wanted more context than that data buffer, you sometimes have to get creative with how to obtain that extra context. While we may disagree on the intent of the OP, I believe my solution serves as a useful alternative to consider outside the bounds of a homework problem.